# Visual Studio Code - Classes and method lists?

Tags: list, function

is there any function list or function outline available in "Visual Studio Code"?
I need it for JavaScript and PHP.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved

Answer (score 38):

Methods are regard as symbols, so you can find symbols as follows
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, then get symbols <kbd>@</kbd>. or get symbols by category: <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>
there's also a shortcut avaiable: <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>

Comment: This does not work for all languages! which is unfortunate

Comment: That depends on whether (a) that language has default support or (b) you've installed the right extension for it. Out of the box visual studio has basic features for all languages, extensions provide the rest.

Comment: As @gideon says, it needs some additional extensions to work. I installed PHP Intellisense and Code Outline, and very importantly I added `"php.suggest.basic": false` to my settings file in order to disable Standard PHP suggestions (this is needed so that PHP Intellisense can work properly)

Answer (score 1):

There is a Show Functions extension which can be configured with regular expressions. Out of the box it works with a lot of languages.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qrti.funclist