# What editor can display function and class structure view of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, editor

You know there are many functions in Javascript file, it's too complex to when a js file grow up.

What editor can display function and class  structure view of Javascript?

Just like Android Studio IDE which can display function and class  of a java file.

[image]

**Js File**

```
function ClassURLPar() {
    this.filename;
    this.diskindex=0;
    this.diskcount=1;
    this.imagefilter = 0;
    this.sortby = 0;
    this.path = "/";
    this.view = 0;
    this.searchtext;
    this.sizemore = 0;
}

var mURL = new ClassURLPar();


function SetMainUIByURLPar() {    
    InimURL();
    SetTabs();
    SetFixedNav();    
    SetControlUI();
    SetControlJump();
    SetModalForm();   
}



function InimURL() { 
    mURL.filename = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
    mURL.diskindex = GetUrlParam('diskindex');  
}
```

Comment: you can check it in webstorm by clicking on `Structure` ub project explorer

Answer (score 1):

I believe almost every modern IDE has such feature as **source structure view**.

Here is a list of popular JavaScript IDE with that feature:

- **WebStorm** ([built-in feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/viewing-structure-of-a-source-file.html))
- **Notepad++** ([built-in feature](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/function-list.html))
- **Atom** (use [plugin](https://atom.io/packages/symbols-tree-view) or navigate by [shortcut](https://discuss.atom.io/t/display-functions-in-a-file/8035))
- **Sublime Text** (use [plugin](http://majutsushi.github.io/tagbar/) or navigate by [shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075317/how-to-get-an-outline-view-in-sublime-texteditor))
- **Visual Studio Code** (navigate by [shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36790558/visual-studio-code-classes-and-method-lists))

Comment: Thanks! does it mean that Visual Studio Code only support? can I download a plugin  which support source structure view ?

Comment: And more, the shortcut in  Visual Studio Code  can't keep display, so I think that   **source structure view** is the better solution

Comment: @HelloCW, I use WebStorm and I like it. I don't really like Microsoft products, especially different Visual Studio's. If you don't want to pay I advise you to use Atom with plugin or Sublime Text. Also some people are happy using Notepad++

Comment: Thanks! I test WebStorm, it's OK, the only bad thing is money.   Notepad++ is hard to config for displaying function list for javascript !

Answer (score 0):

This may be personal opinion but for me it is :

On free IDE

> [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

is best . and if you are ready to pay for it then

> [webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)

is the winner .

Comment: Thanks! I have installed visual studio code, but it seems that it can't display function and class structure view of Javascript

Comment: You can see https://www.dropbox.com/s/swtpo3jpjd5ya9h/vs.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

The best one would be as I use it is developer tools in chrome(you can edit and see the changes in runtime).

If you want to edit at source you can also use Netbeans editor

Answer (score 0):

I think currently best free editors to code with javascript are

> - Visual Studio Code
> - Atom
> - SubLime

All of them are very easy to use and full filling your requirements. Try `Visual Studio Code` first. You can also use chrome developer tools as it shows object structure while debugging and you can test your code with live changes.